# Transposing multiple columns and renaming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

| Product Id | Category | month | sales | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyx | Shoes | Feb | 1000 | 1235 |
| xyx | Shoes | March | 1200 | 1455 |
| aba | Bags | Feb | 14000 | 7235 |
| aba | Bags | March | 5200 | 8455 |

Im trying to semi transpose it - i want one line per unique product id, and to create new columns : feb_sales, march_sales, feb_profit, march_profit. and remove the month column.
Ive tried using

```
table.values.reshape(1, -1), columns=table['month','sales','Profit']
```

and different versions of this but i cannt achieve what im after.
I want the result to be

| Product Id | Category | feb sales | feb profit | march sales | march profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyx | Shoes | ... | ... |  |  |
| aba | bags | ... | .... |  |  |

thank you for any guidance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) - `df.pivot(index=['Product Id', 'Category'], columns=['month'])`

Comment: I should probably add that to convert the multi-index columns how you want them do `new_df.columns = new_df.columns.swaplevel().map(' '.join)` where `new_df` is the pivot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# mage the Category strings consistent:
df["Category"] = df["Category"].str.capitalize()

# pivot the dataframe:
df = df.pivot(
    index=["Product Id", "Category"], columns=["month"], values=["sales", "profit"]
)

# remove the column multi-index
df.columns = [f"{b} {a}" for a, b in df.columns]

# properly sort the columns:
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda k: months.index(k.split()[0]))]

df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Product Id Category  Feb sales  Feb profit  March sales  March profit
0        aba     Bags      14000        7235         5200          8455
1        xyx    Shoes       1000        1235         1200          1455
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you!